# I've accidentally locked out root on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I was playing around with MySQL on OS X and I removed all the 'root' users using `DROP USER`. I then added some of them back and did `GRANT ALL on *.* to 'root'@'localhost';`, and then logged out after verifying that yes indeed, I could log in and do a few privileged operations.

Unfortunately, one of the privileged operations I did not try was `GRANT ALL on *.*`. It turns out that you don't get the privilege to grant privileges with the `GRANT ALL` command. So now I'm stuck. I can't give anybody any privileges to do anything else.

At this point I don't actually have any data in MySQL. I could just wipe the install and do it over. But I would like to fix this without resorting to that extreme. How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the following in a file:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The restart `mysqld` with the [`--init-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) option specifying that file.

Comment: Yay! I figured this one out, but my quest for an answer showed me that nobody had really given a good answer for this scenario on StackOverflow. I was hoping someone would give this answer because it needs to be here. :-)