# Making a user the root

Tags: mysql, sql, database, xampp

Is there any way I could make a user as `root` from xampp GUI ? I do not remember the root password or if, it had any! I want to grant a user all the privileges of the root.

Comment: See [I've accidentally locked out root on MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13975446), replacing the user to whom you want to grant `SUPER` privileges as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to uninstall mysql or anything like that. Please follow my instruction.

1. Stop mysql from xampp control panel
2. Edit `my.ini`
3. Comment out `skip-grant-tables` (your file might look differently, just search for the word `skip-grant-tables` and remove the `#` infront)
4. Save file

[image]

5. Start mysql from xampp control panel
6. Go to phpmyAdmin and log as root (no password)
7. Change your root user password like this (Change function to **MD5** and type your new password on **VALUE**) The picture is just an illustration. Your database should look little bit different:

[image]

8. Press GO button
9. Do Step 1 to 5. However, on Step 3 comment `skip-grant-tables` by putting `#` in front of it

**NOTE**: If you have any issue let me know. I did this several times :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you would have to take a cold backup of your mysql databases and then re-install mysql after uninstalling it *if you want to use the root user*. 
I would appreciate if one could do that without uninstalling mysql. But I think that there is a scarce chance of that.

**Edit** But you can go with @eggyal's way of granting the `GRANT PRIVILEGE` to a user and using that user in the future instead of the root user